# Как правильно сформировать из array_map новый массив?

Tags: php, yii2

У меня есть `array_map` такого вида:

```
$models = array_map(function ($row) {
            return [
                'flat' => $row['flat'],
                'id' => (int)$row['id'],
                'login' => $row['login']
            ];
        }, $dataProvider->getModels());
```

При этом получается, что содержит массивы, в которых отличаются только логины, так как к одной кваритре привязаны несколько `user`

Я записываю логины в новый массив

```
$logins = array();
        foreach ($codes as $row){
                $logins[] = $row['login'];
        }
```

Но не знаю как правильно записать данные в новый массив в котором у меня будет структура:

```
$model = array(function ($row) {
            return [
                'flat' => $row['flat'],
                'id' => (int)$row['id'],
                'login' => array($row['login'])
            ];
        });
```

Пример массива, который приходит с `dataProvider`

```
array (size=5)
  'flat' => string '18 A'
  'ID' => int 56
  'login' => string 'id123'

array (size=5)
    'flat' => string '18 A'
  'ID' => int 56
  'login' => string 'id5454'
```

Comment: проходите циклом и делаете. чо вы пробовали?

Comment: @splash58 не особо понимаю как лучше именно это написать, в голове то как бы понимаю, но вот реализовать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам мешают ключи в выходном массиве, в конце запустите на него array_values

```
$res = [];

foreach($arr as $x) {
    if (isset($res[$x['flat']])) {
        $res[$x['flat']]['login'][] = $x['login'];
    }
    else {
        $x['login'] = [$x['login']];
        $res[$x['flat']] = $x;
    }
}

print_r($res);
```

Comment: То есть это вернет мне просто один массив, в котором будет массив логинов? Вместо нескольких массивом с единичными логинами?

Comment: Сейчас чуть позже попробую в коде это, но может вы раньше ответите. Чисто на вашем примере просто не совсем понятно, что я получу по итогу в $res

Comment: Массив будет, как в последнем коде вопроса  только логин будет массивом

Comment: Ой, я неправильно указал данные в массиве, извиняюсь

Comment: Но в вопросе написал `массивы, в которых отличаются только логины`, только вот пример некорректно составил

Comment: Сейчас попробую применить ваш код, если решит, отмечу галочкой)

Comment: Да, спасибо, это решает мою проблему. Я просто не мог сам написать такую логику с работой по индексам, я скорее хотел писать много форичей и несколько массивов, поэтому искал более красивого решения